# How do I set locale to en_US when testing OpenJDK on Cygwin?

Tags: java

I'm trying to build *OpenJDK* by myself, but there's lots of failures when I run the tests.

I noticed that a large amount of these failures are due to locale settings. Many tests expect an English output, but the locale of my *Windows* is not English.

I tried set environment variable `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8`, but some components like *javadoc* still generates non-English output.

What make this more annoying is that, everytime a test fails, it hangs for a long time before continuing the next test.

Are there anyway to test *OpenJDK* on *Windows* without changing the system locale?

Comment: ```-Duser.country=US``` and ```-Duser.lang=en``` might be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

use -J parameter

```
javadoc -J-Duser.language=en
```